# SharePoint 2010 Upgrade - Service Applications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, managed-metadata, sharepoint-search, secure-store

I am in the process of planning a SharePoint 2010 upgrade to SharePoint 2013 and then to SharePoint 2016.  Both SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016 farms are built and include Managed Meta Data Service, Secure Store Service, Business Connectivity Service, User Profile Service and Search Service.  How does having these services already installed on my SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016 farms affect upgrading these services from SharePoint 2010?  Can I upgrade these services if they are already installed on the SharePoint 2013 and 2016 farms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the Microsoft guidance and recreate the Service Apps with the old databases so that they will be upgraded. I always start with the Managed Metadata Service since the User Profile database, content databases, and others rely on the MMS identities for their values.

For the Secure Store you will need the passphrase so that you can decrypt the credentials.

You didn't mention it, but the Search Service Application has a special comdlet for the upgrade process so that you can preserve your Managed Properties.

If you have a Pluralsight membership I cover all this in my course on upgrading SharePoint. It also includes all the scripts you need.

Comment: Thank you Matthew.  I'm actually watching your video on Pluralsight (Upgrading your Farm to SharePoint 2016.  What happens to the service apps and settings in SharePoint 2013/2016 after I upgrade the old database?  Do I lose all the information currently in the service apps in SharePoint 2013/2016?  Do I keep the  service apps in SharePoint 2013/2016 and rename the SharePoint 2010 service app during upgrade so there are multiples of the same service apps in SharePoint 2013/2016?

Comment: Generally you upgrade from the previous version as your starting point. (You don't create new services first.) The upgraded services are your starting point. You generally don't want to have multiple instances of the service apps.

Comment: Lesson learned.  What is the risk of me upgrading the services over top of the existing services on SharePoint 2013 and 2016?

Comment: The risk is screwing it up and wasting time. As long as you have the backup there is no real risk as long as the databases you are replacing haven't been used. If they have then you will suffer data loss by throwing them away. Personally, I would just delete the Service apps and do it correctly from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Microsoft' article at [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-service-applications-to-sharepoint-server-2016), once old databases are restored in the new SharePoint Farms, the Service application databases are upgraded during creation  of Service Applications in the new Farms.

When we upgraded from SharePoint 2010 to 2013, we restored the old Managed Metadata Service Application Database in the new farm and created the **Managed Metadata** service application by providing the **database** name as shown below

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$mms = New-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Name "Managed Metadata Services" -ApplicationPool "SharePoint XXXXX Service Pool" -DatabaseName "MetaDataXXXX"
New-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy -Name 'Managed Metadata Services Proxy' -ServiceApplication $mms -DefaultProxyGroup


Set-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity 'Managed Metadata Services' -DatabaseName 'MetaDataXXXX'
```

Comment: Thank you Matiur.